# Get request using http module for localhost/same host

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, https, request

i'm trying to send a request for my localhost, from my localhost like this:

```
  http.get
    host: 'localhost:3000'
    path: '/events'
  , (response) ->
    console.log response
```

This is causing this error:

```
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND localhost:3000:80 localhost:3000:80:80
  at errnoException (dns.js:26:10)
  at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:77:26)
```

I can't figure it out why is happening and how to fixed. Can't i send requests for the same server?

Thanks.

Comment: Check in developers tools which url is being hit ? Try hitting [http://localhost:3000/events](http://localhost:3000/events) in your browser and see what response you get..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`localhost:3000` isn’t a host; it’s a host and a port. Pass them as separate properties.

```
http.get
  host: 'localhost'
  port: 3000
  path: '/events'
, (response) ->
  console.log response
```